# Exactness of $2x^2y^3 + x(1+y^2)y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the given equation is not exact but becomes exact when multiplied by the given integrating factor. Then solve the equation.
>
> $$2x^2y^3 + x(1+y^2)y' = 0$$ The integrating factor is $\frac1{xy^3}$

well, the struggle here is showing that it gets exact when I multiply by the integrating factor aka the elementary stuff, differentiation and algebra, any tips/help specifically on this part? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any "tips". Basically just do some algebra and then compute a couple of partial derivatives.

Multiply through...
$$ \frac{1}{xy^3}\left(2x^2y^3+x(1+y^2)y'\right) = \frac{1}{xy^3}(0)$$
$$ \frac{2x^2y^3}{xy^3}+\frac{x(1+y^2)}{xy^3}y' = 0$$
Canceling...
$$ 2x+\frac{1+y^2}{y^3}y' = 0$$
At this point notice that the first part $M(x,y)=2x$ does not involve $y$, so $M_y=0$. Likewise, the second part $N(x,y)=\frac{1+y^2}{y^3}$ does not involve $x$, so $M_x=0$. Since these "mixed partials" coincide, the new equation is exact.

To solve integrate $M$ with respect to $x$, $N$ with respect to $y$, and put together your solution: $x^2-\frac{1}{2y^2}+\ln |y| = C$.